# Starting InstalledAppDetails for certain application is causes force close

Tags: android, android-intent, settings

I am working on an application whose job it is to clear the browser history. As part of this process I send the user to the APPLICATIONS_DETAILS_SETTINGS screen for the browser so they can press the "Force Stop" button, which will close any windows which are currently open in the browser. This is the code that I am using to open up to the app details activity for the browser package.

```
    killBrowserIntent = new Intent();
    killBrowserIntent.setAction("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS"); // I have tried "android.intentaction.VIEW" here as well.
    killBrowserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.android.browser"));
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails");
    killBrowserIntent.setComponent(cn);
```

This works great on many devices. However one of the devices I am testing on this causes a force close with the following log:

```
09-23 08:21:26.231: INFO/ActivityManager(231): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:com.android.browser cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails } from pid 3497
09-23 08:04:23.833: INFO/ActivityManager(231): Start proc com.android.settings for activity com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails: pid=3434 uid=1000 gids={1015, 3002, 3001, 3003, 2001, 1007, 3005}
09-23 08:04:23.843: WARN/InputManagerService(231): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407e4ec0
09-23 08:04:23.873: INFO/ActivityManager(231): No longer want com.motorola.android.deviceinformationprovider (pid 3124): hidden #21
09-23 08:04:23.893: WARN/dalvikvm(3434): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/com.motorola.android.frameworks.jar'
09-23 08:04:23.903: WARN/dalvikvm(3434): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/com.motorola.android.ptt.common.jar'
09-23 08:04:24.083: WARN/dalvikvm(3434): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e560)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1727)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:647)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.onCreate(InstalledAppDetails.java:369)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
09-23 08:04:24.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3434):     ... 11 more
09-23 08:04:24.083: WARN/ActivityManager(231):   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails
```

To dig in to it a bit further I went into settings->Manage Applications->Browser on the device manually and noticed that the Intent that is fired when I do it this way has Extras bundled into it.

This is the Intent line from the Log when this activity is launched manually:

```
09-23 08:23:59.470: INFO/ActivityManager(231): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:com.android.browser cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails (has extras) } from pid 3540
```

This is the Intent Line from when it is launched from my application:

```
09-23 08:21:26.231: INFO/ActivityManager(231): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:com.android.browser cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails } from pid 3497
```

Has anyone come across something like this before? What is the best way for me to figure out what it is that I need to Bundle up and add to the Intent in order for it to properly start on this device?

I've located the source code for the InstalledAppDetails activity, [it can be found here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.4_r1/com/android/settings/applications/InstalledAppDetails.java#) But the line referred to in my exception is 1: outside of onCreate and 2: blank.

Is there a way that I can listen for the Intent that is fired when this activity is opened manually and unpack the extras from it so that I know what they are, and thus what I need to add to my Intent?

Comment: can you give us this line ? InstalledAppDetails.java:369

Comment: My device is running OS version 2.3.4, I found the source code here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.4_r1/com/android/settings/applications/InstalledAppDetails.java# according to that line 369 is blank. It falls between onPause() and onAllSizesComputed()

Comment: are you sure that is the same version? the code and your app?

Comment: Well, considering that it points to a blank line I am almost certain that it is not the same version. I know my device is on 2.3.4 though and this was the only source code I could find for 2.3.4. Also http://android.git.kernel.org/ appears to be down for some reason which is making it more difficult to try to find different versions of the source.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the `setComponent()` call. It should not be needed (assuming the docs are correct), and calling `setComponent()` for a component that is not yours is rarely a good idea. The action string alone should route it to the appropriate activity.

Comment: Removing setComponent() has same result on the device in question, and results in ActivityNotFoundException on all of the other devices that it previously worked correctly on.